# Changing Bonmin options (IPOPT linear solver) within Pyomo

Tags: pyomo, hsl, ipopt

I am using Bonmin through Pyomo/Python, on an Windows machine. Bonmin is being using via binaries, and HSL solvers as well. 
I could change the default solver successfully for Bonmin but IPOPT is still using MUMPS as a linear solver.

I've tried including a bonmin.opt file within the folders (Bonmin's executable or the .py file) but it is not interpreted by Pyomo.

For assigning the linear solver to Bonmin, I use the command line below:

*solver.options['linear_solver'] = 'ma27'*

For assigning the linear solver to IPOPT within Bonmin, I tried many different commands but could not find any that worked. Examples include:

*solver.options['ipopt.linear_solver'] = 'ma27'*

*solver.options['ipopt_linear_solver'] = 'ma27'*

As well as many other different syntax. I have searched throughout Bonmin's and IPOPT's manuals but I still get the same warning if the syntax is accepted:

**NOTE: You are using Ipopt by default with the MUMPS linear solver. Other linear solvers might be more efficient (see Ipopt documentation).**

Otherwise, the syntax isn't even accepted.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

According to the BONMIN documentation [here](https://projects.coin-or.org/Bonmin/browser/stable/0.1/Bonmin/doc/BONMIN_UsersManual.pdf?format=raw),  if you want to set options for Ipopt (when used inside BONMIN) you have to set them in the file bonmin.opt.

Something like this could, hop

```
import pyomo.opt
with pyomo.opt.SolverFactory("bonmin") as solver:
    solver.options.option_file_name = "bonmin.opt"
    with open("bonmin.opt", "w") as f:
        # f.write() # Here you can specify options for BONMIN using the "bonmin." prefix
        f.write("linear_solver ma27\n") # This is the IPOPT option
    solver.solve(model)
```

More information about option files for IPOPT can be found [here](https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OPTIONS.html).

Comment: Thanks, that was as close as I could get to have the code running with ma27 - but now I get a warning as follows. It then goes on to use MUMPS as linear solver instead of MA27. WARNING: Tried to set option "linear_solver" to a value of "ma27", but the previous value is set to disallow clobbering. The setting will remain as: "linear_solver ma27".